# Simplest way to get (jekyll-scholar) plugins on gh-pages

Tags: github, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

GitHub pages does not support [plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/), but plugins are clearly very useful (e.g. [jekyll-scholar](https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar)).

[Nitrous.io](http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/08/30/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html) supports adding plugins to your GH pages site, but this seems a little involved. Is there any simply way to get plugins working on my github [site](http://robinlovelace.net/), or should I just make _site/ the root, as the jekyll-scholar dev. [recommends](https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar/issues/38#issuecomment-32012212)?

Answer (score 3):

The method described in the [Nitrous.io blog post](http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/08/30/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html) can actually be used with a local Ruby/Rails environment, which removes some of the complexity. There's an even [more convenient Rakefile setup from David Ensinger](http://davidensinger.com/2013/07/automating-jekyll-deployment-to-github-pages-with-rake/) that implements the [deployment steps proposed by Randy Morris](https://github.com/randymorris/randymorris.github.com/blob/source/README.md).

Essentially, these Rakefiles are just conveniences to batch the deployment of both your Jekyll source (with plugins) and compiled _site to GitHub Pages as the jekyll-scholar dev recommends. Since [your site](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/robinlovelace.github.io) is a User Pages (username.github.io), then you'll want your compiled _site to end up in `Master`, and your Jekyll source with plugins in a separate `Source` branch. If you want to first experiment with [a Project Page](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/jekyll-scholar-testbed), then you'll want your _site to end up in the `gh-pages` branch (which can be accomplished with [this Rakefile](https://github.com/ainc/awesomeinc2013/blob/master/Rakefile))